# why is the rule not working on Flex using C++?

Tags: c++, macos, flex-lexer, lexer

I have this code, but the action is not working properly using c++.
I've tried, but I don't get any error, what do you think?. Does anybody knows which is the error?.

**ejem05.l**

```
%x use
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_USE_NUM 10
YY_BUFFER_STATE use_stack[MAX_USE_NUM];
int use_stack_ptr = 0;   
%}

%option c++ noyywrap

%%
<INITIAL,use>[0-9]+ {cout<< "Number found: "<< endl;}
use[[:blank:]]+ {BEGIN(use);}
<use>[[:alpha:][:punct:][:digit:]]+ {
    cout << "Nombre de archivo: "<< YYText() << endl;
    if ( use_stack_ptr >= MAX_USE_NUM ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Too much files" );
        exit(1);
    }
    use_stack[use_stack_ptr++] = YY_CURRENT_BUFFER;
    ifstream in(YYText());
    yyin = &in;
    if (!yyin) {
        cout<< "ERROR file not found" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    yy_switch_to_buffer(
    yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ) );
    BEGIN(0);
}
<<EOF>> {
        if (--use_stack_ptr < 0 ) {
            yyterminate();
        }  else {
            yy_delete_buffer( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER );
            yy_switch_to_buffer(use_stack[use_stack_ptr] );
            }
}
%%

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */
    ifstream in(argv[0]);
    yyFlexLexer* lexer = new yyFlexLexer(&in);
    while(lexer->yylex()!=0) 
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

My entry file is:

**entrada.txt**

```
use entrada1.txt
use entrada2.txt
```

The content of the file:

**entrada1.txt**

```
45
56
```

The content of the file:

**entrada2.txt**

```
34
67
89
```

I get this outcome:

> Nombre de archivo: entrada1.txt
> Nombre de archivo: entrada2.txt

I've compiled this file using these commands:

```
flex ejem05.l
c++ lex.yy.cc -o ejem05
./ejem05 entrada.txt
```

The rule that isn't working is:

```
<INITIAL,use>[0-9]+ {cout<< "Number found: "<< endl;}
```

Thanks in advance. I'm sorry, my english is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cause of the behaviour you are seeing, since it is basically undefined behaviour, but it seems likely that it has something to do with the problem.

None of this is appropriate use of C++ I/O objects:

```
{
  // ...
  ifstream in(YYText());    // Point 1
  yyin = &in;               // Point 2
  if (!yyin) {              // Point 3
    cout<< "ERROR file not found" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  yy_switch_to_buffer(      // Point 4
    yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ) );
  BEGIN(0);
}
```

1. `in` has automatic storage duration (i.e. it's a local variable), so it will be destructed when the scope is exited, which will be very soon (but not before it is passed to `yy_create_buffer`. See below.)
2. `yyin` is a member variable, so its lifetime is the lifetime of the FlexLexer object. `&in` is the address of a local object (as noted above). When the block exits, `yyin` becomes a dangling pointer because the object it pointed to no longer exists. Any attempt to use it will be Undefined Behaviour. (I suspect the reason you get away with this is that `yyin` is not actually every used, but I don't know for sure.)
3. Since `yyin` has just been set to the address of an actual object, it cannot be a null pointer. So the test will never succeed. Even if the file was not opened correctly, the error will never be detected. The C idiom is to check the return value of `fopen`, which returns a pointer to a `FILE` and thus could be NULL. The C++ idiom for checking if a file was correctly opened would be:

   ```
   if (!in) {
   ```

   which relies on the overridden [`operator!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!). You could also call `in.fail()`, which has the same semantics.
4. Finally, you pass `yyin` (by reference) to `yy_create_buffer`. The `yy_create_buffer` function is not well-documented (one of the reasons I rarely use the C++ interface myself), but it stands to reason that it does not take ownership of the `std::istream*` which it receives as an argument. (The `yyFlexLexer` object is somewhat documented; in the description of its constructor, the documentation notes that "yyFlexLexer does not take ownership of its stream arguments. It’s up to the user to ensure the streams pointed to remain alive at least as long as the yyFlexLexer instance" and it turns out that roughly the same warning applies in this case. That's not surprising because there is no way that the `yy_create_buffer` member function can copy the `std::istream` object it is passed -- these objects are not copyable -- and without copying, there is no way to take ownership.

   What `yy_create_buffer` does do is to retain a pointer to the `std::istream`'s `rdbuf()`. (This isn't documented, but it's clearly visible in the generated code.) However, because it is a `std::fstream`, when `in` is destructed, it will also dispose of its `rdbuf()`. Subsequently attempting to use the pointer to the destructed `rdbuf` is, of course, more Undefined Behaviour, but if you are very very lucky (or maybe unlucky), enough bits will still be valid in the memory pointed to that the `rdbuf` reports an end of file or an error on the first attempt to read from it. That would definitely explain the symptoms you are seeing, but it is all highly speculative.

Bottom line: If you are going to use C++, play the game by the rules. Don't create dangling pointers, don't let objects which should persist be prematurely destructed, and check `std::fstream` objects' validity after you create them and before you use them.

Comment: ifstream in(YYText()); is destoryed, so the content in entrada1.txt is never read.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly my problem in the code. ^^